# How do I get all the keys in JSON within PHP?

Tags: php, json

How do I get all of the keys and loop through them, echoing each one, from a JSON object array?

Here is my code:

```
/* SAMPLE JSON THAT IS SENT
$mystring = '{
    "display_name": "Silverware",
    "fields": [
        {
            "field_name": "Age",
            "sort_order": 1,
            "required": 0,
            "view_type": "text",
            "description": "",
            "multi_value": 0,
            "char_count": 255
        },
        {
            "field_name": "Brand",
            "sort_order": 2,
            "required": 0,
            "view_type": "multiselect",
            "description": "",
            "multi_value": 1,
            "char_count": 255
        }
    ]
}';
*/


$json = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
$arr = $json->{'fields'};

// This is how I print a specific value
//print $arr[0]->{'field_name'};
```

Adding the following isn't working for me:

```
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    echo $k', ';
}
```

Comment: I am willing to give the benefit-of-the-doubt and say that this is your first dive into PHP. I am proud that you got this far so please add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of your file and try again because you should be seeing an error message. Once you see the error then evaluate what it is telling you.

Comment: Pro-tip: `echo implode(', ', array_keys($arr));`

Comment: `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` was deprecated 5.6 and removed from 7.0 you shouldn't be using it anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `true` for the second parameter of `json_decode()`.

```
foreach ($j['fields'] as $field) {
  $keys = array_keys($field);
  foreach ($keys as $key) {
    echo $key;
  }
}
```